# How to record/access Skype logs

Tags: skype

I am trying to do some sort of analysis on text/chat data 
and though playing around
with my Skype data might be fun.
I have been trying to access the Skype logs from

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Skype\logs`

as was advised in multiple articles about the issue. 
That folder is, however, empty on my machine. 
Am I supposed to enable logging or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last hour or so I had the hell of a Safari tracking down the current location of Skype log files.
Met some great folks on the way; so actually a nice trip.

Try `%AppData%/Local/Packages/Microsoft.SkypeApp_<somehashcode>_/LocalState/<somegibberish>_<myskypeusername>.db`

I also noticed that it´s scrambled; and found out that it´s a SQLite database.
SQLite browser: All (or so I´d say) my chat partners are in the `conversations` table; field `nsp_data` contains config info and the latest message from that chat; but I haven´t found an actual log yet.

The way Skype behaves when I scroll back in time makes me assume that it loads the log from some remote server. I wouldn´t be surprised if there were no more local log files.

Comment: I found the db file, I'll play around and see if it has any useful information. Thanks!